# rails hangs in development mode, ExecJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, execjs

My project suddenly began to hang out on page loads, in development mode.
The behavior is very strange, the browser or curl just processing the request.
I desperate.

Caching is turned off.

I took [config/environments/development.rb](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10041277/) from new empty rails project.

I think the blame ExecJS, beacues when I remove line

```
javascript_include_tag 'backend', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
```

from layout file everything works fine.
The most outrageous thing is that I nothing changed in javascript for a while.

I tried remove NodeJS from system and add gem 'therubyracer' to Gemfile

But nothing changed.

Sometimes even Ctrl+C does not stop the server and I have to close the window with the console with rails server.

Now execute rails with this command

```
rm -rf tmp/* && rails server
```

Help me please.

P.S. ruby 2.2.0p0, rails 4.2, ubuntu x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in assets.

/config/initializers/assets.rb

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(comments: :none) 
config.assets.compile = true
```

I tried to compress javascript on every request.

Solution, move this 2 lines in to /config/environments/production.rb

Stupid mistake, which is very hard to find.

Comment: Same here... very very stupid and hard to find. Thanks for posting this.